# Установил Ubuntu рядом с windows 10, но загружается только windows и нет выбора загрузки системы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

Установил Ubuntu рядом с windows 10, но загружается только windows и нет выбора загрузки системы, выбрал в меню установки 1й пункт, автоматическая установка рядом в Windows 10, установка прошла успешно, перезагрузил комп, загрузился windows и нет никакого выбора системы для загрузки, что делать?

Answer (score 3):

Вставить флешку с ubuntu  и восстановить GRUB

- http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub_legacy
- http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub